How can one formally show that $ B(x,r) \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^{k_0} B(x_j,1)$, where $x \in \mathbb R^n$, $R_0 > 0$ and $x_j \in B(x,R_0)$?
I am currently studying an article and amid one specific objective, the author uses the following observation:

Consider arbitrary elements $R_0 > 0$, $x \in \mathbb R^n$. One easily checks that there exists $k_0 \in \mathbb N$ (depending only on $R_0$ and $n$) and $x_j \in B(x,R_0)$, $j = 1,\dots,k_0$ such that $$ B(x,r) \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^{k_0} B(x_j,1), $$ for any $0 < r \leqslant R_0$.

Intuitively, I think that what the author means is that, given a point $x \in \mathbb R^n$, we can always cover a certain ball (in this case, $B(x,r)$) by taking a finite number of balls with unitary radius centred at elements that belong to a greater ball (in this case, $B(x,R_0)$).
I feel like my interpretation is correct and I've drawn some diagrams that make me believe in this statement but I can't find a way to formalise it. Therefore, the main goal of my question is to pursue a somewhat formal proof of this observation that the author made.
Thanks for any help in advance.

It suffices to consider $r = R_0$.

@PaulFrost Thanks for your comment. That's because each ball $B(x,r)$ is contained in $B(x,R_0)$, for any $0 < r \leqslant R_0$, correct?

This is correct!

@PaulFrost So the question essentially becomes how to formally prove that there exists $k_0 \in \mathbb N$ and $x_j \in B(x,R_0)$, $j = 1 ,\dots, k_0$, such that $$ B(x,R_0) \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^{k_0} B(x_j,1). $$ Do you have any hint on how to proceed after this update?

consider the closed ball and conclude by compacity? EDIT: Afntu beat me to it

I think the answer should describe how $k_0$ depends on $R_0$ and $n.$ See for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105699/how-many-1-balls-are-needed-to-cover-the-2-ball-in-an-n-dimensional-euclidean

You do not say whether balls are open or closed, but I guess they shall be open.
Let $X = \overline{B}(x,R_0)$ be the closed ball which is compact. The open balls $B(y,1)$ with $y \in B(x,R_0)$ cover $X$: Obviously each $y \in B(x,R_0)$ is contained in $B(y,1)$. For a boundary  point $y \in X$ (which is characerized by $\lVert y - x \rVert = R_0$) we pick a point $y' \in B(y,1) \cap B(x;R_0)$. Then clearly $y \in B(y',1)$.
Since $X$ is compact, it is covered by finitely many balls $B(x_i,1)$, $i =1, \ldots,k_0$,  with $x_i \in B(x,R_0)$.
The number $k_0$ can be made independent of $x$. To see this, let $x = 0$ and $k_0$ an adequate number of open balls $B(x_i,1)$ covering  $B(0,R_0)$. Now shifts all balls via a translation by $x$. Then clearly $B(x,R_0)$ is covered by the balls $B(x_i+x,1)$.

Thanks, this makes more sense than the previous answer due to the fact that the open cover you present only considers centres in $B(x,R_0)$ instead of the closed ball $\overline{B(x,R_0)}$. I understand your reasoning. The only thing that is not yet clear is why doesn't $k_0$ depend on $x$ ?

Let $R_0 >r$, then consider the closed ball $B[x, R_0]$, a compact set in $\Bbb R^n$. Now consider an open cover $\{B(y,1): y \in B(x,R_0)\}$ of $B[x,R_0]$. We must show that it is an open cover of $B[x, R_0]$. Let $z \in B[x, R_0] \setminus B(x,R_0)$, then consider an open ball $B(z,1)$ and let $y_1 \in B(z,1)\cap B(x,R_0)$, then observe that $z \in B(y_1,1) \in \{B(y,1): y \in B(x,R_0)\}$.
As it is a compact set, it has a finite subcover, which means there exists $x_1,\cdots,x_{k_{0}} \in B(x, R_0)$ such that $B(x,r) \subseteq B[x, R_0] \subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^{k_0} B(x_j,1)$.

Thanks for your answer. You begin your answer by taking advantage of the open cover $$ B[x,R_0] \subset \bigcup_{y \in B[x,R_0]} B(y,1), $$ which is obviously true. After this, you say that since the closed ball is compact, such cover admits a finite subcover which then leads you to the elements $x_1,\dots,x_{k_0}$, but how do you guarantee that these points belong to $\mathbf{B(x,R_0)}$ ? Furthermore, according to your answer how do you guarantee that $k_0$ doesn't depend on the choice of $x$ ?

I updated my answer, which contains your first question. But for the second question, as there is no information about $r$, If we assume $r$ is fixed, then by changing any $x \in \Bbb R^{n}$, the size of the ball will not change; it is a translation of the open ball in $\Bbb R^n$, so after translation also it requires same number of open balls to cover the set.
